# Unix script is sorting the input

Tags: bash, unix

I am having sometime here with my home assignment. Maybe you guys will advise  what to read or what commands I can use in order to create the following:

Create a shell script test that will act as follows:

1. The script will display the following message on the terminal screen:
   Enter file names (wild cards OK)
2. The script will read the list of names.
3. For each file on the list that is a proper file, display a table giving the ten most frequently used words in the file, sorted with the most frequent first. Include the count.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 over and over until the user indicates end-of-file. This is done by entering the single character Ctrl-d as a file name.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter file names (wild cards OK)'
read input_source
if test -f "$input_source"
then
```

Comment: Please ask a single, specific question. IE not, "I'm not sure how to do this assignment.", but "How can I find the ten most frequently used words in a file?".

Comment: Let's start with the first part. You are supposed to read a *list* of names. Are you treating the input you get as a list (i.e. many things) or as a single item (i.e. one name)? How will it make a difference? Imagine I enter after your prompt: `filename1 filename2 filename3`. What does your test do with that input?

Comment: assuming there is a word per line: sort $input_source | uniq -c | head -10

Comment: Also, if you are completely lost about shell scripting, I recommend that you take a look at something like this first: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.

Comment: @tigran …which would give you the ten *least* frequently used words in the file.

Comment: You state this is a home assignment?  I'm assuming for school?

Comment: @kojiro I don't think so : ( echo a; echo a; echo b; echo a) |sort | uniq -c

Comment: Thanks guys. Yep that one is for school. I mostly confused about the following part:
Repeat steps 1-3 over and over until the user indicates end-of-file. This is done by entering the single character Ctrl-d as a file name.
Should I loop this script at this point ?!

Comment: @tigran I was wrong. It would give you a group of ten words used some frequency, but with no guarantee of being the least or most used words. You need to sort again to order the output of `uniq -c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm usually ignoring homework questions without showing some progress and effort to learn something - but you're as beautifully cheeky so i'll make an exception.

here is what you want

```
while read -ep 'Files?> ' files
do
    for file in $files
    do
        echo "== word counts for the $file =="
        tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '\n' < "$file" | sort | uniq -c | tail | sort -nr
    done
done
```

And now = at least try understand what the above doing...

Ps: voting to close...

Comment: wow. Thanks. I am currently having couple of books opened regarding shell scripting :)

Comment: Your use of `ls` is adding a bug for files with whitespace: the file `file with spaces` will go through 3 iterations of the for loop.

Comment: Amended. This is the safest way to iterate over files.

Answer (score 1):

### How to find the ten most frequently used words in a file

Assumptions:

1. The files given have one word per line.
2. The files are not huge, so efficiency isn't a primary concern.

You can use `sort` and `uniq` to find the count of non-unique values in a file, then `tail` to cut off all but the last ten, and reverse-numeric sort to put them in descending order.

```
sort "$afile" | uniq -c | tail | sort -rd
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. have access to the complete bash manual: it's daunting at first, but it's an invaluable reference -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html
2. You can get help about bash builtins at the command line: try `help read`
3. the `read` command can handle printing the prompt with the `-p` option (see previous tip)
4. you'll accomplish the last step with a `while` loop:

   ```
   while read -p "the prompt" filenames; do 
       # ...
   done
   ```